# Deleting rows in DB yii2

Tags: yii2, relational-database, sql-delete

I have "components" that I make  relation between them , and if I want to "update" the information about some component related to other,I must delete the related "component" and the relation 
[image]

. In actionUpdate I have :

```
 public function actionUpdate($id) {
    $model = Component::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one();
    $tractorModels = ArrayHelper::map(Tractormodel::find()->all(), 'id', 'model');
    $components = Component::find()->all();
    $depModels = Dependency::find()->where(['component_id' => $id])->all();
    $deletedIDs = Yii::$app->request->post("deletedIds");

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        $dependendComponents = Yii::$app->request->bodyParams['ids'];
        foreach ($dependendComponents as $dComp) {
            $dependencyModel = new Dependency();
            $dependencyModel->setAttributes([
                'count' => $dComp['quantity'],
                'component_id' => $model->id,
                'dependent_id' => $dComp['id']
            ]);
            $dependencyModel->save();
        }
        if ($deletedIDs && is_array($deletedIDs)) {
            Dependency::deleteAll(['id' => Yii::$app->request->post()["deletedIds"]]);
       }
        return $this->redirect(['index', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
                    'model' => $model, 'tractorModels' => $tractorModels,
                    'components' => $components, 'depModels' => $depModels,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and in the view  I use jQuery to get the deleted items in array with id (deletedIDs) , and to delete the relation and related "items" to the components

```
 wrapper.on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) {

        var wantedDiv = $(this).parent('div').children().first();
        var selectTag = $(wantedDiv).find('select');
        var clickedId = $(selectTag).find('[selected=""]').attr('value');
        var deletedIdsArray = $('#deletedIDs');
        console.log($('#deletedIDs'));
        if (clickedId) {
            $('#deletedIds').append('<input type="hidden" name="deletedIds[]" value="' + clickedId + '">');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    });
```

Everything is ok on "theory" but the components dont delete in the DB , I look if

```
 if ($deletedIDs && is_array($deletedIDs)) {
        Dependency::deleteAll(['IN', 'id', $deletedIDs]);
   }
```

work , and I var_dump($deletedIDs)
and got the array with the items I want to delete,but the components that are related to the "item" when I delete them don`t disappear. Can someone tell me what I miss ?

Comment: I tried myself and `deleteAll` method works fine to me (is array and contains multiple IDs. So it probably works in your case, too). What you can try is to use `try` and get exceptions (to see what's wrong).

Comment: I try it ,but it don`t delete them in the Database ,  var_dump work , and it seems to catch them and going to delete them , but actually dont delete them , and that`s a bit acquard  ( here is my var_dump with all elements I want to delete , so I  think I miss something but cant figure out what) . And yes , the array cointains every ID from each "component" I want to delete .
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "15"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "13"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "16"
}

Comment: Ok, then try to delete row directly from database and see if it lets.

Comment: 1 row deleted. (Query took 0.0550 seconds.)   , directly from phpmyadmin
and on refresh they remain only 2 "components" related to the "main component"

Comment: Ok, that was not quite what I have expected. I'll take a look later, right now I'm short on time.

Comment: okay , thanks   you

Comment: Solved it :  Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->delete('dependency', ['dependent_id' => $deletedIDs])->execute(); instead of 
 Dependency::deleteAll(['id' => Yii::$app->request->post()["deletedIds"]]);

Comment: Interesting case. But it should have worked with `deleteAll` too because it worked for me well. I can't tell why this didn't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it :

```
 Yii::$app->db->creat‌​eCommand()->delete('d‌​ependency', ['dependent_id' => $deletedIDs])->execu‌​te();
```

instead of

```
Dependency::deleteAl‌​l(['id' => Yii::$app->request->‌​post()["deletedIds"]]‌​);
```